# In Django Rest Framework Serializer, how to get the full path of image?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my project, I want to get the full path of image using Serializer class.

When I use ViewSet class, it seems to get correct result. But when using APIView class, it doesn't get what I need.

```py
# the model
class UserAccount(models.Model):
    ...
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='icon/user')
```

```py
# the serializer
class UserSerializer(serialziers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAccount
        fields = (..., 'icon')
```

Use ViewSet

```py
# viewset
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

# result
# {..., 'icon': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/icon/user/filename'}
```

Use APIView

```py
class UserView(APIView):
...
def get(self, request):
    ...
    userAccount = user.userAccount
    serializer = UserSerializer(userAccount)
    return Response(serializer.data)

# result
# {..., 'icon': '/media/icon/user/filename'}
```

What should I do to get full path of the image in APIView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add additional field with `SerializerMethodField`:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    icon_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserAccount
        fields = (..., 'icon_url') 

    def get_icon_url(self, user_account):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        icon_url = user_account.icon.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(icon_url)
```

And add `request` to context in view:

```
def get(self, request):
    ...
    userAccount = user.userAccount
    serializer = UserSerializer(userAccount, context={'request':request})
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works just as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR;

> See the updated section.

For the same purpose i created a reusable mixins that can be inherited on serializer class.

```py
from django.db.models import FileField, ImageField

def get_full_url(request, path):
    """Get full url with respect to current scheme"""
    url = request.scheme + "://" + request.get_host() + path
    return url


class FileFullPathSerializerMixins:

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        request = self.context['request']
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        for field in instance._meta.fields:
            # returns the full file path for the below instance db cols
            if field.__class__ in [FileField, ImageField]:
                field_val = getattr(instance, field.name).name
                if field_val:
                    data[field.name] = get_full_url(request, field_val)
        return data
```

**Usage Example:**

```py
class UserProfileSerializer(FileFullPathSerializerMixins,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'avatar', 'email')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'email': {'read_only': True}
        }
```

> Caveats: Make sure you pass the request as a context from the viewset as:

```py
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(UserProfileViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"request": self.request})
        return context
```

**Updated:**
If you're using FileField or ImageField in the serializer field. There there's no need to modify the actual response.

```py
class FooSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(source='image_field')
    file = serializers.ImageField(source='file_field')
```

> There's no need to manually modify the internal representation of api response using `to_representation` method if you're using ImageField or FileField in serializer. Just passing the request as a context to the serializer works fine otherwise above approach works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just give "request" instance inside of serializer context, while initializing it, and if there any ImageField, drf automatic will generate full path of you file(image).

Like:
Without request inside of context:
media/images/...
With request inside of context:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).